# How to merge 2 queries in 1?

Tags: clickhouse

I have two requests that do the same thing, but for different groups.

```
SELECT count() FROM Table1 WHERE label = 'label1' AND group IN (0) AND date >= '2018-01-01' AND date <= '2018-02-01';

SELECT count() FROM Table1 WHERE label = 'label1' AND group IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) AND date >= '2018-03-01' AND date <= '2018-03-01';
```

Can I split it one query?

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL`. [Link](https://clickhouse-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/query_language/queries.html#union-all-clause)

Answer (score 3):

You can use..

```
UNION ALL
```

..between the two queries to only get one result returned. It will still be two queries however, if you want it to be one query, you can use CASE WHEN .

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN group = 0 AND date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01' THEN 1 END) As Group1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN group IN (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) AND date BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-01 THEN 1 END) As Group2
FROM Table1 
WHERE label = 'label1'
```

Comment: Please note that the time period for the second query was just one day. I also 
switch the >= and <= to BETWEEN.